# asp.net, razorpages: how to put a confirmation box in between actions

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I have this URL action:

```
 <a href="@Url.Action("DeleteCat", "GlobalTagging", new { id = Model.MainNodes[i].Id})">Löschen</a>
```

this triggers a function in my code behind:

```
 public ActionResult DeleteCat(int? id) { }
```

The problem is that I am not able to insert a confirmation dialogue (yes / no) in between.
I tried with javascript:

```
     function DeleteCat(value) {
*ALERT*
           @Url.Action("DeleteCat", "GlobalTagging", new { value})
       }
```

But the issue is, that I cannot pass the js param to the c# function as they are from different runtimes.

So I need to trigger the alert from the code I guess, but I haven't found any valid solution.

I did come across this:

```
Response.Write("<script>alert('Data inserted successfully')</script>");
```

But I wasn't able to inflate a dialogue box with a yes / no option and respond to it. Maybe this code can be altered, so it can be used inside c#?

Any idea is welcome!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `click` event either via the `onclick` attribute of your anchor or by calling `youritem.addEventListener('click', redirect);`

```js
function redirect(event) {
    if (!confirm("Are you sure")) event.preventDefault();
}
```

```html
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com" onclick="redirect(event)">Foo</a>
```

```js
    function redirect(event) {
        if (!confirm("Are you sure")) event.preventDefault();
    }
    document.getElementById("foo").addEventListener('click', redirect);
```

```html
    <a id="foo" href="https://stackoverflow.com">Foo</a>
```

Comment: you sire, are a gentleman and a scholar!